# One button on widget doesn't work

Tags: android, button, click, widget

I don't know what is wrong in my code, but everytime i put widget on home screen button1 doesn't work. After phone reboot both buttons works perfectly...

```
package cro.perger.bonbon;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



        public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                        int[] appWidgetIds) {

                            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");

                            for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

                                Intent callIntent1  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                                         Uri.parse("tel:*100" + encodedHash));
                                Intent callIntent2  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                                         Uri.parse("tel:*200*1" + encodedHash));

                                PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent1, 0);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent2, 0);

                                RemoteViews views1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                                views1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent1);

                                RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                                views2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);

                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views1);
                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views2);
                            }

                }
    }
```

Any help, please ??

EDIT 2 : Ok, now it's working, but now I have another two questions . First i managed three buttons for sending messages, but I always get the same Message body, no mather what button I press. And second what do I need to change this code, so thah message is sent automaticly (now only composed message is opened) ....

```
package cro.perger.bonbon;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



        public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                        int[] appWidgetIds) {

                            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");

                            for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

                                Intent callIntent1  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                                         Uri.parse("tel:*100" + encodedHash));
                                Intent callIntent2  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                                         Uri.parse("tel:*200*1" + encodedHash));

                                Intent sendIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent1.putExtra("sms_body", "Poruka 1");
                                sendIntent1.putExtra("address", "5556");
                                sendIntent1.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                                Intent sendIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent2.putExtra("sms_body", "Poruka 2");
                                sendIntent2.putExtra("address", "5556");
                                sendIntent2.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                                Intent sendIntent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent3.putExtra("sms_body", "Poruka 3");
                                sendIntent3.putExtra("address", "5556");
                                sendIntent3.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                                Intent openintent = new Intent(context, bonbon.class);

                                PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent1, 0);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent2, 0);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent5 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent6 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openintent, 0);

                                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent1);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, pendingIntent3);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button4, pendingIntent4);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button5, pendingIntent5);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button6, pendingIntent6);

                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

                            }

                }

        }
```

Comment: Could you specify the variable that is causing trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do there is updating the same widget (`appWidgetId`) with two layouts (`views1` and `views2`). Basically you are setting the widgets layout with a pending intent on `button1` (->`views1`).
Then you overwrite it with a layout where only `button2` has a pending intent (-> `views2`). I'm not sure why this is working after a restart, maybe android notices that you use the same base layout resource and doesn't create it from scratch somewhere in the internals.

*So how do you do it correct?*

You may just shorten your snippet. Create one layout, set the pending intents for both buttons on the same layout and update as you did. But only once, you will never need more than one call to `updateAppWidget()` per `appWidgetId` (this is basically the same thing that setContentView() is for a normal activity).

Should look like this in the end:

```
Intent callIntent1  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                             Uri.parse("tel:*100" + encodedHash));
Intent callIntent2  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                     Uri.parse("tel:*200*1" + encodedHash));

PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent1, 0);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent2, 0);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent1);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Comment: Thank you this helped :) Now everything is working perfect :)

Comment: Ok, my code now looks like first post... And i can't get to work button3 that needs to send an SMS. (i found this type of intent in some other question) ...

Comment: That seems mostly correct, the only thing I see (and had trouble in the past with) is the flags parameter in the 3rd getActivity(). Most people pass 0 to this and most of the time it actually works. But sometimes extras don't get send with the intent (which is critical here) - I never saw where the docs state that 0 is a valid option. Try to replace the last 0 argument with PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or any other valid one from the docs (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Comment: Then I recommend opening a new question. I don't know an answer here, it's way easier to post code snippets and links in a new question and people coming from search engines will find every issue seperated. And more people will look into it, almost no one will look here since already answered.

Comment: Hey. It's working ... but can you please see Edit2 in my answer, maybe you can help me with that...